# How to add a line under a button?

Tags: html, css

I have a button like below with a line underneath. This is achieved by using `text-decoration-line: underline`. My problem with this is the line is only as long as the text in the button (All).

How can I get it to be the same length as the button while the button's corner remains a bit rounded as it is?

[Edit]: My apology, I've forgot to add that I use `btn` class from bootstrap. One of the answers is what I what I want to achieve but with `btn` class from bootstrap. Again, my apology.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

use pseudo-elements
Like this

```css
button {
  position: relative;
}
button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.6rem;
  background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);
}
```

```html
<button>HelloWorld</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

border-bottom: 2px solid black;

you can set border bottom below the button, also you can adjust paddings and stuff to make your line look good.

In case of rounded ones, border-radius is the option possible

Another way is to add < hr / > tag

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the helps but I've fixed this by wrapping the button in an element and have the underline works for the parent of the button instead of the button. This means the underline is for the parent's element not the button itself which allows the underline to have the same width as the button.

Comment: Are you not gonna mark this as correct? This question looks unanswered if you will not read any post

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to increase the left and right padding of the text element. When the text element plus its padding-left and padding-right have exactly the same width as the button itself, it will look like you want to have it.

For you to achieve this you have to remove the button padding first, otherwise you'll just get double padding and the border would never go all the way out to the sides. You can overwrite Bootstrap in your own stylesheet, for example like this:

```
.btn {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.btn a {
  padding-left: 2.2rem;
  padding-right: 2.2rem;
}
```